# script async defer undefined attribute name

Tags: eclipse, asynchronous, xhtml, deferred

I have an xhtml file in Eclipse Oxygen

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and I try to use

```
<script async="defer"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&amp;callback=initMap" type="">
</script>
```

However I got "Undefined attribute name (async)" notification. What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: `async` is HTML 5 only not XHTML

Comment: Without async, does google map function as it should be?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script async="true" defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&amp;callback=initMap" type="">
</script>
```